# Not displaying object values in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jdbc

I have an object class through my jdbc, where i want to display all orders, when a customer is logged in.

i have a class in my database to access all orders:

```
public static ArrayList<OrderSample> showOrders() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, LoginSampleException {
    try {
        ArrayList<OrderSample> order = new ArrayList();

        Connection con = Connector.connection();
        String SQL = "SELECT * from useradmin.users";
        Statement statement = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(SQL);
        while(rs.next()){

        int id = rs.getInt("idorder");
        int height = rs.getInt("height");
        int length = rs.getInt("length");
        int width = rs.getInt("width");

        OrderSample o = new OrderSample(height, length, width);
        order.add(o);
        }
        return order;
  } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
        throw new LoginSampleException(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

and then i have a servlet method to put the information to a session object, from a command superclass to handle all requests:

public class Employee extends Command {

```
@Override
String execute(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws LoginSampleException {
    try {
        ArrayList<OrderSample> orders =UserMapper.showOrders();
        request.setAttribute("orders", orders);

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Employee.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Employee.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    return "employee";
}
```

when i try to loop trough the order objects to display them in my jsp, they don't show

```
 <c: forEach items="${order}" var="order">
     <tr>
         <td>Order to delete </td>

    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: The code puts a single `order` in request scope (not session scope) as "order", but an `order` is not a collection.  Perhaps use the entire `orders` instead of a single `order`.

Comment: +1 on what Andrews S stated, plus, there are several questionable chunks of code happening as well.  In your `showOrders()` method, there is a `try` statement without a `catch` statement.  In your jsp the `<c: foreach>` has a space in the name.  Not sure that matters or not but I would not have that space there.  In your servlet code, you are ending up setting only one `OrderSample` in the request instead of the `List` of `OrderSample`s.  Meaning, that there won't be a collection by the time you get to the jsp and the `<c:foreach>` won't have anything to iterate over anyways.

Comment: so i have to write orders in the var?

Comment: I have changed the code approprietly, however it's still not working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting your response object in the `HttpServletRequest`.  You will have to set the response content type appropriately, and then set the content itself in the response body.

Comment: How i set the reponse content type?

Comment: There is a `setContentType` method on `HttpServletResponse` object.  Check the API for `HttpServletResponse`:  https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html

Comment: So i just insert orders as a string in the content type. Thank you for your help btw

Comment: No, content-type would be `text` or `json`.  The actual content would go in the body.

Comment: i'm not using json, so for a POJO object as my order, it would be text?

Comment: The POJO would still have to be converted to some data format, whether that's text, json, xml, etc.  To write to the response body use: httpServletResponse.getWriter().write("String representation of your POJO");